# PowerShell: how to get URL string from line? Beginner

Tags: regex, shell, powershell

How do I write a Power Shell script with a that scrapes one website and extracts one url from within a public static html file?

I am having trouble getting just the link, I can only get the line that contains the link.

'Invoke-WebRequest' downloads and saves the html file.

The link I want ends in .m3u8 so I use

'Select-String' to search for .m3u8 and PowerShell returns one line. But I want a link, not a line, the line contains other normal html markup that I don't want. The link is in double quotes and ends in .m3u8. I want what is inside the quotes.

Should I use split to convert the line into an array?

Should I use regex to "only get what is inside of quotes"? and if so how?

```
$variable_text = index.html
$variable_line = sls .m3u8 $variable_text
$variable_url = sls "regex inside of the quotes" in $variable_line
```

When I google regular expressions and enter them into powershell the command returns the ">>". Perhaps my problem is with syntax? The online regular expression checking tools work but when I put that regular expression into powershell it never works. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) might be helpful for you. Especially the example 2. No need to use regex. ;-)  ... and BTW: Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

No need to download the website or parsing thru all lines.
The `Invoke-Webrequest` cmdlet contains a property named links.

Example of getting all links and searching for the m3u8 link:

```
$WebSite = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "your website"
$Links = $WebSite.Links.href
$Links | Where-Object{$_ -like "*.m3u8"} #Will show you all links which end with .m3u8
```